# Create a link to a text file in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I create a link in XAML to open a text file?  The text file directory is same as the project directory.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Click="openFile_Click">Open File</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

In order to get current application path you can use [AppDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx) Please notice that AppDomain.BaseDirectory includes "\" to the end of the path.

```
var appPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

and to execute your file you can do:

```
private void openFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(appPath + "myFile.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_Click">Click Me..!!</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("filePath");
}
```

---

Say file name is `ABC.txt`.

In case **file is not copied to output path** and is added in project as Resource, you can give relative path like this to open the file (assuming your file is added directly under the project):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("..\\..\\ABC.txt");
```

In case **file is copied to output path**, you can directly give file name since by default it will look for file in output path:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ABC.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

IF it is MVVM then try below codes in xaml

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding CommandPath}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=RecordID}">
        <TextBlock Text="Open File" />
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

and in viewmodel

```
public ICommand CommandPath { get { return new DelegateCommand(HyperlinkClick); } }

private void HyperlinkClick()
{
    Process.Start(@"notepad.exe", @"C:\TEST_FILE.txt");
}
```

Comment: Yes,i am using MVVM.Could you give me the solution?